# Bash: tsort with tie-break

Tags: bash, sorting, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to be able to topologically sort a directed graph, but be able to specify the tie-break sort used.

Eg, given:

```
horse cat
dog cat
elephant cat
cat mouse
mouse snake
dog snake
elephant snake
```

I would like to sort tie-breaks alphabetically.

`tsort` gives the following output:

```
elephant
dog
horse
cat
mouse
snake
```

I would like:

```
dog
elephant
horse
cat
mouse
snake
```

Is there any easy way to force this behaviour? I cannot alter the source list but can manipulate it before applying tsort. The solution must be bash, but I am not wedded to using tsort itself.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to sort by name the key pair that would have the same topology order.

In that case, you could simply perform a "standard" sort before `tsort`.

```
sort file | tsort
```

The (GNU) version of `tsort` I'm using doesn't have an option to do that type of sort.

Comment: Correct. Is tsort always guaranteed to produce the same output for an alphabetised source list? It seems like it might do that, but by accident rather than design.

Comment: I don't know if this is by design, but that's how I used it and so far so good ;-)

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work (in fact, it *doesn't* work when I try it). The original input already lists `dog cat` before `elephant cat`, but `elephant` still appeared before `dog` in the output of `tsort`.